# Searching a specific data property, if true, add a different data element to current cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Firstly, sorry if the question is worded badly. I will try my very best to explain.

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have a column with the name Size, that will either have the value 1500 or 1200. What I want to do is If the value of this is 1500, add the Weekly Losses (Cost) column value of the same row to the cell T33.

[image]

I have tried using multiple =IFs like `=IF(Z8=1500, +T8, IF(Z9=1500, +T9))` but obviously when the first if statement if reached I believe it stops the formula and just populates it with the value of T8.

I have also tried looking at alternate options such as VLOOKUP, but I from what I have found this will also not work?

I'm unsure of the use of =IFS but could this be a solution?

Be greatly appreciated with any help provided, it has been one of those head wreaking moments for me.

Thanks

Comment: I believe you are looking for [`SUMIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Comment: such as simple solution. Thanks so much

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad is there a possible way to find out how many of the criteria is true? I have to find the average, so if the criteria is met 10 times, then / 10, if its met 6 times / 6?

Comment: I have used a =COUNTIF function in another sell for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @cybernetic.nomad for this simple solution.

Anybody that is looking for something similar I will highlight what Ive done.

The function <kbd>SUMIF()</kbd> solves this issue.

- =SUMIF require `3` parameters which is detailed below.
- =SUMIF(`range of cells that are being evaluated`, `criteria(value youre looking for)`, `sum-range the cells you are going to add up if criteria is met`)

Taking a look at my example I used the formula which worked perfectly!

```
=SUMIF(Z8:Z23, 1500, T8:T23)
```